# How to import google code project to android studio?

Tags: android, google-code

I recently came across a cool project (https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/) I would like to import to android studio. Is it possible to import this without trying to copy-paste individual code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you would have to extract the apk to make it easier, or if you just want to run it the apk is located in the downoads section

Comment: How would on go ahead and do that?

Answer (score 0):

Those projects contains *.project* and *.classpath* files. Those are meta-data for eclipse IDE and unfortunately there is no *build.gradle* so it cannot be imported immediately in Android-Studio.

The best thing to do is to write a *build.gradle* yourself for this project and then opening it into Android-Studio. It's a good exercise to learn gradle if you are not familiar with it yet.